# Removing characters from already built hboxes

Tags: boxes

Section 5.9.6 of [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) shows an algorithm for dissecting a vbox into the individual lines in form of hboxes by repeatedly removing the last line with `\lastbox`. Similar commands exist for removing other components of boxes, namely `\unskip`, `\unkern` and `\unpenalty`.

The same doesn't seem to work when trying to dissect hboxes, unfortunately. The following sample illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\def\inspect{%
    \unhbox0
    \count0=\lastnodetype
    \setbox1=\lastbox
    \fbox{\box1}, \the\count0
}
\setbox0=\hbox{abc}\hbox{\inspect}

\setbox0=\hbox{ab\hbox{c}}\hbox{\inspect}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

When we try to use `\lastbox` to remove the last character from the first hbox, the result is just a void box. Printing the node type with `\lastnodetype` shows why: the last character isn't a box but a "char node" (node type 0). When wrapping the `c` into an extra `\hbox`, the result is as expected a "hlist node" (node type 1).

Is there a way, in (La)TeX/e-TeX only, to traverse the contents of an already built hbox similar to the vbox approach? The e-TeX documentation lists 16 types of nodes that may occur in lists, but I can only see a way to remove five of them once they have been added to a list.

Comment: You can't remove a character (unless you use LuaTeX).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible without LuaTeX.

Of course with LuaTeX it is easy, but you have to decide how to store the glyph because there is no TeX register for storing isolated `glyph` nodes.(Glyph nodes are the char node equivalents in LuaTeX, you would loose information about the font if you stored them using `\chardef`)

One option is to store a glyph node wrapped in a `\hbox` in a box register:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\setlastcharbox{\directlua{
  local nest = tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr]
  local tail = nest.tail
  if tail.id == node.id'glyph' then
    tail.prev.next = nil
    nest.tail = tail.prev
    tex.box[token.scan_int()] = node.hpack(tail)
    print(tail)
  else
    tex.box[token.scan_int()] = nil
  end
}}
\begin{document}
\def\inspect{%
    \unhbox0
    \count0=\lastnodetype
    \setlastcharbox1
    \fbox{\box1}, \the\count0
}
\setbox0=\hbox{}\hbox{\inspect}

\setbox0=\hbox{abc}\hbox{\inspect}
\end{document}
```

[image]